# Apache 2.4.7 .conf file layout doesn't notice directory directive

Tags: ubuntu, web-server

I brought up my webserver with new Ubuntu 14.04 today and bump in to an uncomfortable problem here

regardless what im trying apache doesn't recognize the directory directive or may be the DocumetRoot for my webapp

in my .conf file are two lines

```
Document Root /var/www/webapp
Directory "/var/www/webap"
```

000-default.conf is disabled and the directory line in here is changed from

```
/var/www/hrml to /var/www
```

When I use the Server name now the browser ends up in /var/www but doesnt in /var/www/webapp

Any ideas?

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize"?  Are those typos on `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory "/var/www/webap">` or is that directly copied from you config file?

Comment: It shows the directory listing of /var/www instead the index.php of the webapp sub directory.  The typos I made are not in the coding file I made it here because 'I have had to hurry. 

I found the Issu. But it is wired the index php file is only shown if mod_rewrite is activated.

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentRoot` should be ONE WORD. You're using `Document Root` (notice the space)
Same for your Directory directive, you have a typo there (`/var/www/webap vs /var/www/webapp`)